# Why isn't IDependencyResolver generic?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am wondering why the IDependencyResolver isn't generic. The `GetService` and `GetServices` are returning object(s), and I am thinking if there was a good reason to not using generics here instead of `object`?

I am using ninject as a custom dependency resolver in my MVC 5 application.

```
 public class NinjectDependencyResolver:IDependencyResolver
{

    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        //ninject specific implementation
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        //ninject specific implementation
    }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brad Wilson explains this in this article here (http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/service-location-pt5-idependencyresolver.html).  Essentially, there are generic versions, but they are extension methods.  Here is an excerpt:

> You may have noticed that there are no generic versions of GetService
>   or GetServices on IDependencyResolver. We provide extension methods
>   for IDependencyResolver which provide these generic methods:
>   By using extension methods, we have simplified implementation of
>   IDependencyResolver, while consumers of the interface can use either
>   the early-bound/strongly-typed generic versions (and avoid the cast in
>   their code) or the late-bound/weakly-typed versions (sometimes useful
>   when you want to create an instance of a concrete type that you expect
>   to implement a specific interface or derive from a specific abstract
>   base class).

What I have been unable to find or determine is if this is still the case for MVC 5.

Comment: It is still [in the stack on codeplex](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/IDependencyResolver.cs), and was updated 16 hours ago.